# Angular1 - ng-repeat from a function doesn't update when the underlying model changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a block of checkboxes on an `ng-repeat`, however instead of the `ng-repeat` being a scope object direct, it is on a function that flattens a multi-level array that is in scope called `$scope.customReportsCtrl.districts`.

HTML

```
<li class="option"
    ng-repeat="district in customReportsCtrl.subDistricts()
               | orderBy: customReportsCtrl.districtOrder | limitTo: 4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="district"
           id="d{{district.IDSubDistrictLogical}}cbx" class="custom"
           ng-model="district.selected"
           ng-change="customReportsCtrl.districtSelectionChanged(district)"
           ng-disabled="!customReportsCtrl.shouldDisplayDistrict() ||
                        (customReportsCtrl.selectedDistrictsChecked == 
                         customReportsCtrl.selectedDistrictsLimit
                         && !district.selected)"><!--
    --><label for="d{{district.IDSubDistrictLogical}}cbx">
          <span></span>{{district.SubDistrictName}}
       </label>
</li>
```

Angular Controller function:

```
$scope.customReportsCtrl.subDistricts = function(){
    var subDistricts = new Array();
    angular.forEach($scope.customReportsCtrl.districts,
      function(districtDetail, districtKey) {
        angular.forEach(districtDetail.subDistricts,
          function(subDistrictDetail, subDistrictKey) {
            subDistricts.push(subDistrictDetail);
        });
    });
    return subDistricts;
}
```

Display and interaction is working fine. But now I am trying to make a function that deslects all items. I am attempting to do this by updating the `$scope.customReportsCtrl.districts` model. But it has no impact on the HTML.

```
function resetDistrictSelections() {
    angular.forEach($scope.customReportsCtrl.districts,
      function(districtDetail, districtKey) {
        districtDetail.checked = false;
        angular.forEach(districtDetail.subDistricts, 
          function(subDistrictDetail, subDistrictKey) {
                subDistrictDetail.checked = false;
        });
    });
}
```

The whole thing seems a bit messy. Am I right in assuming that because the `ng-repeat` is using a function, it doesn't have hold of the returned object's state?

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTML uses `ng-model="district.selected"`, change the function as follows:

```
function resetDistrictSelections() {
    angular.forEach($scope.customReportsCtrl.districts,
      function(districtDetail, districtKey) {
        districtDetail.checked = false;
        angular.forEach(districtDetail.subDistricts, 
          function(subDistrictDetail, subDistrictKey) {
              ̶s̶u̶b̶D̶i̶s̶t̶r̶i̶c̶t̶D̶e̶t̶a̶i̶l̶.̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶e̶d̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶;̶
              subDistrictDetail.selected = false;
        });
    });
}
```

That will uncheck all the checkboxes.